# Magento 2: How to Enable Layered Navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I've successfully implemented the layered navigation in Magento 1x but I can't seem to get it to work in Magento 2x.

There's a good guide that can be found here: www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-how-to-enable-layered-navigation

But following it, I just couldn't get it to work.

The categories and sub categories as attributes are just not showing up in the left sidebar.

Anyone?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you set thte category as anchor?

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason and even if I did re-index and flush the cache numerous times, the products just magically appeared. I also already add products in those categories so they should've shown up ...

Well, i'm stumped :) Follow the guide, it'll work itself eventually.